# MUI DataGrid - forcing filter and sort state to be reset when getting new data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I recently starting using the mui DataGrid. I have it on a page with a drop down that fetches different data when an option is selected and passes that new data to the rows prop. I just noticed that if I set a filter/sort and then change to another item in the drop down, the filter and sort are still applied. In other words, if I am looking at a list of 100 items and set a filter that reduces it to 10 items and then change the item in dropdown to fetch new data, the new data isn't being displayed (unless it happens to match the filter of course).

How can I simply remove the filter on demand? Basically run whatever logic runs when you click the delete icon in the default filter window (x icon).

Or is there another way around this? I don't see any props or configurations to control this. I'm using the non-pro version.Version 5.1.1

```
function GridExample() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // for grid
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState(""); //id in dropdown

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
       const payload = await getGridData(selectedData);
       setData(payload.data); //replace w/new data
    }

    if (selectedData !== "") {
       getData();
    }
  }, [selectedData]);

  function handleDataSelectionChange(e){
     setSelectedData(e.target.value);
  }

  const gridColumns: GridColumns = [
     {
       field: "Id",
       headerName: "Id",
       width: 300,
       hide: true,
       hideable: false,
       filterable: false,
     },
     { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 300 },
     { field: "description", headerName: "Desc", width: 500 },
     {
       field: "enabled",
       headerName: "Enabled",
       width: 150,
       valueGetter: (params: GridValueGetterParams) => {
          return params.row.enabled ? "Yes" : "No";
        },
       },
     ];

     if (data) {
       return (
           <div style={{ height: 650, width: "100%" }}>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%" }}>
                 <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <DataGrid 
                      columns={gridColumns} 
                      rows={data} 
                     />
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         )
      }
  }
```

Comment: I think because you're adding `selectedData` as a dependency. So whenever the id in dropdown changes, it will cause a re-render

Comment: Hmm. But that's what I want. I need the effect to fetch new data when they choose a new id. Otherwise, it'll run on every render when any other state on the page changes and I'll have infinite re-renders.  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

That reset button is not exposed. How about if you refresh the page when new data is selected with a reload in your function?

```
  function handleDataSelectionChange(e){
   setSelectedData(e.target.value);
     window.location.reload()
   }
```

Comment: i'll try it. thanks

Comment: No, that's definitely not an option. I have mui tabs and this page is a child of the third tab and when it reloads it obviously starts on the first tab. There must be a way to programmatically remove the filter.